# Unable to update object in array item using mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

this has been bugging me over the weekend and couldn't get a solution working.

I have the collection below and i'm trying to replace a whole title with another.  i.e. completely replace title no. 1 with another object with the same attributes but different values..

I'm using mongoose v6.2.1 (although tried rolling back to v5) with nodejs v16.13.2,

```
{
  "category": "Books",
  "titles": [
    {
      "no": 0,
      "name": "Space Master",
      "defaultEdition": 3,
      "tags": [{ "name": "Adventure" }, { "name": "Space" }]
    },
    {
      "no": 1,
      "name": "Train Driver",
      "defaultEdition": 10,
      "tags": [{ "name": "Thriller" }, { "name": "Train" }]
    }
  ]
}


let newBook = {"no": 0, "name": "New Book", "defaultEdition" : 12, "tags":[] }
await Library.findOneAndUpdate(
  { category: "Books", "titles.no": 0 },
  {
     $set: { "titles.$": newBook}
  }
);
```

Each time I try to update, there is no error but the data returned (and in the db) has not been updated.

I've read many similar issues and tried numerous combinations.  I got it working in mongodb playground in vscode but not through mongoose  :-(.

Even just tried to simplify it to update one attribute of the existing book object wouldn't work, like this:-

```
await Library.findOneAndUpdate(
  { category: "Books", "titles.no": 0 },
  {
    $set: { "titles.$.defaultEdition": 20}
  }
);
```

Please help me........

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error and it works fine for me. Can you please share your schema? Also note that `findOneAndUpdate` returns the original document. To get the updated one you need to add `{new:true}`.

Comment: Thank you, it was in my model / schema that I hadn't defined correctly for titles.  It's working now, will remember to check the models next time!